# Two line text for MenuItem

Tags: android, menuitem, multiline

Do you know how to have a two lines menu item title? I've tried using \n in the string or Html.fromHtml with 
 tag but it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the recommended answer from Google:
"If text in a simple menu wraps to a second line, use a simple dialog instead. Simple dialogs can have rows with varying heights."

https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus

Answer (score -1):

You can use `String line=System.getProperty("line.separator")`

---

this will give you newline effect in string.