# Android: String value with new-line in XML

Tags: android, xml

I have a menu item with a somewhat long name, be it *"My very very, very extremely first android menu item inflated!"*.

The problem: the text is presented in a single line, and cut at the area of 'menu'.
But even if the text would fit, I'd still not want it to occupy all the space from left
to right, and prefer a line break somewhere reasonable.

The question: how do I trigger a line break in the XML file (values/strings.xml)?
The line is simple:

```
<item android:id="@+id/MyFirstItem" android:title="My very very, very extremely first android menu item inflated!"/>
```

Eclipse rejects anything starting with a `'<'` inside the string so that's a no-go.
Also, I don't want to leave the bounds of XML.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply \n works for me.

Edit: For general XML usage you would want to use parameters like

```
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

instead of adding your own linebreaks (of course, this doesn't apply to strings.xml, but for your layout). It's time-consuming and may lead to your application looking 'wrong' on different phones / resolutions.
Just in case you didn't use it already, not implying you are doing anything wrong. :)

Comment: '\n' didn't work for me :/  Perhaps I was not clear enough:  
My app is very simple, of the "Hello World" kind, and my menu as well. The menu is inflated using a MenuInflater object, and I see the menu item's title all displayed in a single line which is eventually cut:
{
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/MyFirstItem" android:title="My very very, very\nnew-line here first android menu item inflated!"/> 
</menu>
}
Yet the 'new-line here' text appears as the rest of the line.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ALevy Yeah, I see what you mean. I misunderstood and I see the issue now (I have the same thing when testing) - I really don't know if you can have multiple line menu texts. It kinda makes sense as usually menu items are "About", "Help", "Settings" or similar. The \n command works for non-menu item strings.

Comment: Hmmm... somewhat limiting... Thanks for the layout tip though :)

Comment: Yeah. :/ I could be wrong though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713598/two-line-text-for-menuitem seems to have the same issue. Only thing I can think about trying is doing it via Java code and using \n inside the string you supply as a parameter on setTitle(CharSequence title), but I don't think it will work. Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html

Comment: Indeed, when specifying `setTitle("Line one\nLine two")` the `\n` simply translates to a space, so I believe your initial assumption was right - Android doesn't want new-lines in menus, and I'll have to resort to shorter titles.