# how to make the menuItem show text in two lines?

Tags: android, menuitem, word-wrap

The `menuItem` is used in `ActionToolbar` and `popupMenu`. The text in the `menuItem` is long and would like to wrap it into two lines. I Tried use "\n" and seems it is replaced with space. Searched and not able to find a solution.

Tried the following, not work:

```
<string name=“long_name_menuitem”>This is a\nlong name item</string>

PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);

popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, id, Menu.NONE,     
    getResources().getString(R.string.long_name_menuitem));
```

or or define the menuItem

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_lone_name”        
    android:title="@string/long_name_menuitem"/>
```

Anyone has idea how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713598/two-line-text-for-menuitem but unfortunately there is no answer there. When an answer is found, these questions should be combined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Action Bar Two Line Text Labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943069/android-action-bar-two-line-text-labels)

Comment: Tupac you are still alive. I love your music. OP try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083569/android-menu-line-break

Comment: It seems that the \n should do the trick... In this Question they seem to have tried it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943069/android-action-bar-two-line-text-labels

Comment: @Neo, '\n' does not work.

Comment: @android_Muncher, that link is not solution for me, it should be simple as setting some flag.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?