# Multiple line text in navigation drawer menu

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to wrap my text in a nav-tab 
It doesn't display everything if the phone isn't horizontal

Here is my xml code fot the nav tab:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_scan"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/nav_option_scannen" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_import"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:title="@string/nav_option_import"
        android:visible="true" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_export"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:title="@string/nav_option_export" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools"
        android:visible="false" />
</group>
```

and the 2 strings that are not fully displayed

```
<string name="nav_option_import">Besucherliste importieren</string>
<string name="nav_option_export">Besucherliste exportieren</string>
```

[image: Doesn't display fully when phone is vertical]

[image: Does display fully when it is horizontal]

if I am trying to ad a "\n" in the string it doesn't work as well, furthermore I would like the text to wrap automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two line text for MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713598/two-line-text-for-menuitem)

Answer (score 2):

[image]
[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

use this match parent

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to use this?

Comment: @stdunbar just updated and added a image. hope you get it.

Comment: @naveen what about landscape view? This will occupy also the whole landscape screen that is in most cases not a desired behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an appropriate property to do so, however you can use `android:titleCondensed` property to display a shorter title when there's not enough space to display the whole title string. Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource)

Answer (score 1):

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxWidth="350dp"
```

Try to use `android:maxWidth` attribute. It defaults to 280dp. You can overwrite it to achive a desired width of the drawer.